# How do I focus the AG Grid after it loses focus?

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a function that causes the grid to jump multiple rows. I use the endless row model of the grid, so jumping over 30ish rows at once will prompt the grid to rerender the next few rows after the jump and lose focus on the grid as a whole. Any other key events on the page at the time will instead be processed as part of the surround page element rather than as part of the grid.

How do I put the grid back into focus after this jumping of rows? I assume it is an HTML issue, as none of the grid api functions (if attached to the function) will work due to the grid's html being out of focus, and I cannot add a global event listener to the function's key presses because then it would mess up other properties on the page. How would I go about refocusing it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to scroll to a certain row and select the first cell you need to get the focues cell and remember its row index:

```
// remember previous index
var lastRowIndex = gridApi.getFocusedCell().rowIndex;

// perform your actions...

// scroll to index
gridApi.ensureIndexVisible(lastRowIndex);

// select first cell/column 
gridApi.setFocusedCell(lastRowIndex, columnApi.getAllDisplayedColumns()[0]);
```

If you need to scroll to the grid itself, you can use:

```
const element = document.getElementById("gridId");
element.scrollIntoView();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp

Comment: Hello! I'm trying to manage cases where the grid itself loses focus, not just focusing the rows. As an example, say the 'Enter' key on my grid is set to scroll to row 10. If I press Enter while the grid is in 'html focus', then it will scroll to row 10. If I click anywhere else on the webpage that the grid is on to put focus on those elements instead, then Enter will no longer act upon the grid and instead will act upon the element I clicked on. I want to gigure out how to refocus the grid after each time I press 'Enter' so that it will not lose focus without doing a global event listener.